# Pattern for managing large user uploaded datasets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, dataset

I'm a relatively noob programmer.  I am creating web based GIS tool where users can upload custom datasets ranging from 10 rows to 1million.  The datasets can have variable columns and datatypes.  How do you manage these user submitted datasets?

Is the creation of a table per dataset a bad idea? (BTW - i'll be using postgresql as the database).

My apologies if this is already answered somewhere, but my search did not turn up any good results.  I may be using bad keywords in my search.

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain a bit more about how the data will be used? Also is the structure of the data arbitrary or a subset of a larger set of columns/datatypes?

Comment: The data will be used to dynamically generate markers and heats maps for their map.  They'll also be able to filter the dataset based location or data values.  There wont be any cross dataset joins.  Some datasets will be used to create trending graphs about a specific location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creating a table per dataset is not a 'bad' idea at all.  swivel.com was a very similar app to what you are describing and we used table per dataset and it worked very well for graph generation on user uploaded datasets and comparing data across datasets using joins.  we had over 10k datasets and close to a million graphs and some datasets were very large.

you also get lots of free usage out of your orm layer, for instance we could use active record for working with a dataset (each dataset is a generated model class with its table set to the actual table)

pitfall wise is you gotta do a LOT of joins if you have any kind of cross dataset calculations.

Comment: when you say generated model class (assuming RoR), do you mean dynamically generate AR models or did you actually create a corresponding model class in your app?  The later sounds unlikely but want to be sure.

Comment: What was the largest dataset you guys had in a table?

Comment: dynamically generate a class for each table.

Comment: i do not recall the what the largest single was, but it was over 100megs easy, possibly a few gigs.

Comment: I decided to pursue this option.  I will report back on how it goes (as far as testing).

Answer (score 1):

My coworkers and I recently tackled a similar problem where we had a poor data model in MySQL and were looking for better ways to implement it. We weighed a few different options, including MongoDB, and ended up using the entity attribute value model. The EAV model is essentially a 3-column model. It allowed us to a single model to represent a variable number of columns and data types.

You can read a little about [our problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789458/need-advice-is-this-a-good-use-case-for-a-nosql-database-if-so-which-one), but it sounds like it might be a good fit for you too.

Comment: I've been thinking a lot about this approach.  One of my colleagues recommended it.  We are using rails btw.

Comment: Our application is in Rails too. We ended up writing the data access functionality outside of Active Record though since each large data set is in a separate table and we didn't need the extra functionality or overhead.

Comment: How was the query performance on this table as it grew?  I read through your post and looked like you were doing atomic inserts rather than a batch load like we will be doing.  I think our batch loads will slow down to keep up with indexes as the table grows.

Comment: We've been batch importing a backlog of 1-3 years worth of data, and then loading new data as it comes in every 15 minutes. We ran a ton of benchmarks to make sure the performance was up to par after the initial load and subsequent loads. Some of the data sets we're importing have upwards of 200+ columns which is about 7 million records/year at 15 min intervals. One thing to note is we are typically querying < 10 columns at a time. It's very fast for this subset, but querying 100+ columns is very slow. I would definitely recommend testing it out and seeing if it meets your performance needs.